# How can I discretize an in-build colormap?

Tags: matplotlib, colors

I want to plot an elevation map using "terrain" colormap. But, I want to discretize it by the boundries that I select. For example:

```
bounds = [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 3000, data.max()]
```

Is there a way of discretizing a ready colormap?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will discretize the colormap in N colors and set it as default color cycle when you will plot.

```
from matplotlib import rcParams, cycler

N = 6
cmap = plt.cm.terrain
custom_cycler = cycler(color=cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, N)))
ax.set_prop_cycle(custom_cycler)
```